# why pandas nsmallest faster than sort_values

Tags: python, pandas

- Why pandas nsmallest **faster than** `sort_values().head()`?

  - [pandas doc notes that nsmallest **faster than** `sort_values().head(`)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html)
  - **Test picture:**

[image]

```
   - x axis: k (k in top-k)
   - y axis: time consumed (Unit: Seconds)
   - red point: sort_values(kind="heapsort")
   - greend point: sort_values(kind="mergesort")
   - blue point: nsmallest()
```

- How pandas to implement `nsmallest`?

  - I want to know that.. thank you.

Comment: Don't know about pandas, but `min(l)` is O(n), and can be adapted to store the `k` smallest values in O(n.lg k) with a priority queue, although `sort(n)` is O(n. lg n).

Comment: i see, like Maximum heap to find top-k is O(nlogk). but I don't know nsmallest if it uses this algorithm...